# Cakephp 3 trouble modifying Collection

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I'm making a collection and one of the tasks is to make it Match any campus_id that is not = to NULL and not equal to campus.campus_name of 'Online'

`$onCampusesLocationsHc = $collection->match(['enrollment_type_id' => 1 ])->match(['location_id' => 1 ])->match(['campus_id' => !NULL]);`

this works great so far but having trouble adding the "or not equal to campus.campus_name of 'Online'".

I've added

`->match(['campus.campus_name' => 'Online']);`

it will not work if the first condition is applied.

`->match(['campus_id' => !NULL]);`

but it will filter everything out but the Online category. 
If this line is added instead of the !=NULL is present

I've tried to run the opposite but the result is empty.

`->match(['campus.campus_name !=' => 'Online']);`

It should return Six campuses.

Struggling to find something in the Collection Filters that will allow me to apply two filters to a column.

Comment: First, let's start with the fact that matcher filters do only apply basic equality comparisons, they don't support operators or anything. Also note that `!NULL` is not the same as `value != NULL`, the former will simply evaluate to boolean `true`, and  compare the value against that, ie `value == true`. That being said, I'm having a hard time figuring out what your conditions should look like exactly, as you're first saying you want to use `AND`, but then you're saying `OR`?

Comment: If you want to filter your collection, it seems that you might want the [filter](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/core-libraries/collections.html#filtering) functionality, which lets you provide a function that inspects each item and return `true` or `false` depending on whether you want to include it.

Comment: ndm yes I see your point. I am first evaluating to make sure that there is a value in the campus_id field. once I have that list I need to filter out the "Online" campus from the list. So Yes it should be first "IS NOT NULL" and "IS Not Online".

Comment: I'll look at the filter again to see if It might work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Greg Schmidt lead me to the answer. I used the reject() filter

->reject(function ($notOnline, $key) { return $notOnline->campus->campus_name === 'Online'; })

by adding a reject function on the end I was able to reject anything that had a campus name of Online. The other six campuses now show up